# Create new column for count of previous day in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has category in the first column and date in second and count of occurence in the third.

I want to add a new column that will show the count of occurence of that category on the previous day. I have upload the picture of the Table.
Sorry i am new here and apologies for the mistakes.

```
Category Date Count Count yesterday
C1       D1   10          ?
C1       D2   15          ?
C1       D3   25          ?
C2       D1   25          ?
C2       D2   34          ?
```

Comment: `SELECT *, '?' yesterday FROM my_table;`

Comment: @Strawberry - LOL

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Hey, I expended more effort on this than the OP. What do you want? ;-)

Comment: Create a view instead, to avoid data inconsistency.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something you should do in your reporting logic (i.e. middleware) via query. Storing counts for previous day in the same table is not something I would recommend because:

- Maintaining these values would be difficult. With each insert, update or delete, you will have to update the rows with previous day's counts as well
- Your table won't be normalised anymore

I would write a `SELECT` query to get the counts by day and display in the report UI whenever required.